# Using *args and **kwargs with special parameter in Python

Tags: python

Reading the [offical document](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#special-parameters), I learned that I can use two special symbol `/` and `*` to specify positional and keyword arguments range.

When function need to receive variable `arguments(*args)`, how to define this function?

keyword variable `arguments(**kwargs)` works as expected.

```py
def function_args_s1(p1, p2, /, pk1, pk2, *, k1, k2, **kwargs):
    pass

function_args_s1(1, 2, 1, pk2=2, k1=1, k2=2, k3=3, k4=4)
```

but variable `arguments(*args)` meet some error.

```py
def function_args_s2(p1, p2, *args, /, pk1, pk2, *, k1, k2):
    pass

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```py
def function_args_s3(p1, p2, /, pk1, pk2, *args, k1, k2):
    pass

pk1 and pk2 are no longer use keyword parameter because they before *args
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you provide more detail or sources about this syntax ? I would like to clarify the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*args` argument in a function is capturing all remaining positional argument, which means it also does what `*` does.

```py
def function_args_s2(p1, p2, /, pk1, pk2, *args, k1, k2, **kwargs):
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)
```

Then

```py
function_args_s2(1, 2, 3, 4, k1=5, k2=6)
()
{}
function_args_s2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, k1=7, k2=8, kw1=9, kw2=10)
(5, 6)
{'kw1': 9, 'kw2': 10}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not have `*args` and `/` in the same signature. `*args` allows for multiple arguments, `/` does not.